# Android : Dimming down screen

Tags: android, screen

I would like to dim-down my screen in my project as im working on.
I have an android phone that runs 2.2. It works great if I use the following code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.screenBrightness = 0;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

But when I tried the code on the emulator and on phone of my friend, that both runs 2.3, it goes to lock screen and i dont know why. Anyone who has an idea how I can dim the screen down for 2.3 devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 0.01f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

This is probably not the best way to fix this particular issue, but it works.

Comment: Yes, this works, actually even 0.005f seems to still be working. Problem is (at least in my case) that the screen backlight is still too bright even in that case. I actually looking for a way to entirely dim the screen, so that when the room is entirely dark, you don't even see where the screen is anymore, across the room). But with 0.005f, you still see the device's backlight. But I guess, for most other cases, this solution is a good workaround.